# running 2 processes in parallel on haskell

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing

i want to run 2 processes in parallel, one waiting for input, and as soon as it gets it changes the satate of a variable, and the other process is constantly printing something in the screen, both comunicate in a way that, the input collected by the first process can modify what the other process prints on the screen

the problem is that i want the second process to be printing constantly on the screen while the other is waiting for input, but the only thing i get is that the second procces blocks until the first one gets the input and then continues, im using windows

```
main = do
    r <- newMVar (4,4)
    forkIO (act1 r)
    act2 r
  where
    act1 r = forever $ do
        dot <- takeMVar r
        c <- getCharNoBuffering 
        putMVar r (newDot dot c)
    
    act2 r = do
        forM_ [1..20] $ \_ -> do
            dot <- takeMVar r
            print (position dot)
            putMVar r (newDot dot)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do the `takeMVar` in `act1` it removes it so that act2 can't take it to print it. I would change `act1` to do a `modifyMVar` and even then wait until you have the new character. Also for `act2` you can use `readMVar` since there is no reason to remove and re-insert the value.